# Confusing question

Tags: discussion, support

I do not want to come across as rude, but am I the only one who has trouble understanding [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7710/should-krishna-be-considered-good-or-bad) and what the OP wants as an answer? OP has answered his question, but even that does not make much sense to me. And after reading all the comments, it seems like he isn't interested in others' view of it.
Shouldn't such questions be flagged? If yes, under what category?

Comment: IMHO as it stands the question can be answered by an expert who has read the entire mahabharata (such as @KeshavSrinivasan). The question simply asks 'if Krishna was God, then why did He have to kill Karna, Dhrona, Bhishma, etc. in different ways'. The answer would simply be an explanation of each act and why it was justified as per Mahabharata. All the best. As for the OP's answer to His own question, I think Keshav's comment is the appropriate thing to inform the user to cite sources. All the best

Comment: I do agree the question could be reworded :)